# SQL Join creating duplication in output

Tags: sql, sql-server

SO i Have a query which, due to my database requires a lot of tables to function. Unfortunately, this is an older database, which is a little problematic to navigate.

This query, originally checked whether a Membership was to be 40 or 50 years in length which was easily solved. However, Now I have to see whether a an attribute telling me whether they are reinstated members which would invalidate this timeline is present.

I have managed to get show and exclude records, but the the error I believe I have made, is in using an outer join as I was attempting to check multiple records in the joined table for this condition, which has lead several cases to duplication as multiple different attributes can be contained in the same column

I am just trying to make sense of this currently, but believe I have used the incorrect join because where an individual has a different attribute from this result it returns an additional record.

My question is which Join should I be using, or should in this instance I be looking at writing a sub query within the where condition

Comment: Some additional data would be nice.

Comment: What you mean by `older database`, which version sql you are using . If you are uncertain query `select @@version`. Most people here want to see sample data , error output and expected output. I guess a good read on `joins` will solve your problem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx

Comment: [Forum Etiquette: how to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). We don't have access to your data, nor should we, so we need some Consumable Sample data to go with the question, which demonstrates the problem. Otherwise, all we can do is guess. and my guess is that your `ON` or `WHERE` clauses are wrong for your needs. Without further information, there's little more users here can really offer.

Comment: please share sample data by editing it in the question or providing a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Apologies to all, I can't share data due to GDPR rules and internal policies, hence my cryptic approach.

I'm not sure how I could create consumable data for you on short notice which would be compliant and actually show you the issue.

Comment: @Sparkind you can actually change column names and row data to a sample format. All we need is sample data, we do not want any sensitive information

Comment: If you cannot post an example then I doubt we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this myself by using a Sub-query.

The nature of the the requirement meant that it was difficult for me to produce a list which eliminated the duplicates, because i was looking in a joined table for results which may or may not appear.

So i used a sub-query in the where clause to look for the the instances where what i was trying to exclude which was producing the false positives did appear and use the use those results to eliminate those primary keys from the original table that way using a Not In Primary Key.

Probably not the most efficient but it does work within a couple of seconds

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an LEFT/RIGHT or OUTER JOIN. These JOINs have a smaller result. Or you might use DISTINCT - this forces the result to not return duplicates.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but I believe the duplication's are resulting from the fact that in the table I need to Join too, the key from the original table can, by the design of the table be either absent or appear multiple times.

This is why I was wondering whether I should have performed a sub query within the where statement, but I am now realising that I probably need to query within the join statement itself.

Comment: @Sparkind did u join on primary keys and their datatypes aligned correctly ?

Comment: @BHouse Yes i did and I beleive that yes they do., Sorry I hit return by accident. The issue is that the primary key from the main table, can be design appear multiple times within the joined table. There isn't really another way to link them either.

Comment: @Sparkind it means primary key column of first table is not referenced to PK or FK of another table. And, the join table has columns repeated more than once ?

Comment: @BHouse thats exactly it. The Joined table is essentially a list of Attributes we assign to a scheme member. The PK May, May not or may appear multiple times.

What I'm trying to do is join this, then exclude individuals whom have a specific attribute. the issue is where they have more than one attribute in this second table, they can test both negative and positive for having the attribute at the same time.

Comment: @Sparkind         You can join as a subquery  using distinct column names, i would appreciate if you can add sample data i.e column names and few rows of data from first table and the same from second table

Comment: @BHouse I'm just trying this at the moment. I'll get back to you once I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **distinct** with specified names of the columns. Maybe by using that you won't get the duplicate columns.

`eg. select distinct ed.id, ed.name, ed.dob, ea.address, ed.Emailid from Employeedetails ed join Employeeaddress ea on ed.id = ea.id`